# Forwarding from one gmail to another - recipient automatically skips inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Two email accounts, `alpha@gmail.com`  and `beta@gmail.com`

I set up a filter on alpha.

```
If to:(alpha@gmail.com) then:
forward to:beta@gmail.com
skip inbox
mark as read
```

I want it to come in like a normal new email on my beta account (unread, in inbox), and be filed away in my alpha account.

When a test email is sent, the email is read/archived in **both** accounts.

If I removed the 'skip inbox/mark as read' instructions from the filter, then it will come to inbox/unread on both accounts.

If I separate the filters (one to forward, one to read/archive), it arrives read/archived in both accounts.

In the beta account settings, alpha@gmail.com is set up as a "Send mail as" account. The 'alias' box is not ticked.

Comment: Are you looking at these two accounts in different browsers/tabs or have you linked them through the settings?

Comment: Well.. both. I have two browser windows open to control each, but they are linked via settings in that beta's settings has alpha listed as a "send mail as" account.